# Mostrar qué usuario hizo una pregunta sólo a usuarios administrador (admin) en php

Tags: php

Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca el usuario que hizo una pregunta en un help desk?

Quiero usar la sesión de php para lograr mi objetivo, pero creo que si intento usar la sesión para identificar el usuario obtendré el id de administrador con el que me he identificado previamente.

Qué pasos podría seguir para lograr mi objetivo?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Para entender mejor cómo funciona esta comunidad, date una vuela por el [tour] del sitio. Para que tu pregunta sea respondida es necesario que sepas [ask] y respetes el principio de incluir un [mcve].

Comment: Para hacer una pregunta en ese help desk es necesario estar logueado ??

Comment: si claro pero el admin se encarga de ello osea de hacer el registro el usuario se logea y lo direcciona al help desk

Comment: brother, preguntas del tipo de sugerencias son cerradas por estar basadas en opiniones. Revisa los enlaces que te dice el buen @KroneauxSchneider. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Debes capturar el usuario de la persona que realizó la pregunta, puede ser algo así: `$usuario = $_SESSION['user']`
2. Después de capturar ese usuario lo puedes guardar en un campo de la tabla en la que guardas las preguntas
3. Cuando un admin se loguee simplemente debes llamar ese campo como llamas todo lo demás (titulo, descripción, incidencia, etc etc etc)

Listo con eso es suficiente para que un administrador sepa que usuario hizo la pregunta..

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: donde tengo que poner el $usuario

Comment: Lo capturas y lo guardas en la parte del código donde estés guardando las preguntas